# It throws an error "Index out of range" when I try to remove a value from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I'm newbie programmer, and not talented yet, I stucked in an error and I can't handle it for days. I have problem with `indexpath`, when I try to remove something from `Dictionary` it throws an error, `“fatal error: Index out of range“`

Briefly, I showed my `dictionary` and `tableview` in the below, and `numberofrows` and members may increase or decrease, I’m adding these members to dictionary when I checked one of them on `tableview`, and it adds selected one without any problem. But problem begins when I remove one of my selected ones, I think the cause is index numbers, because their index numbers are changing when they included to dictionary. I want to remove exact person that I select, but how it's going to be possible?

For example, when I remove by unchecking person3, there must only person1 and person5 in dictionary. If the code and error is not clear, please let me know.

this is how looks of my tableview, members list;

```
1. person1 ✔️   // -> index 0 
2. person2
3. person3 ✔️   // -> index 2
4. person4
5. person5 ✔️   // -> index 4
```

selected ones added to dictionary

```
var selectedUser = [NSDictionary?]()   
var friendsDic = [NSDictionary?]()

// Inside of selectedUser after the adding members.
[{
    email = “person1@gmail.com";    
    id = jqvDUcBoV9Y4sxir5kR0dg1;   // person1 index is still 0 
    name = person1;
    profileImageUrl = "<null>";
}, {
    email = “person5@gmail.com";    // Now person5 index is 1
    id = hVfS9EU6LWatAynJNyDmum4A2;
    name = person5;
    profileImageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/findyourfrienddemo.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FAE5ED4E4-CF53-4AC4B628.jpg?alt=media&token=eb969e-57290d7e02c9";
}, {
    email = “person3@gmail.com";    // and person3 index is 2 
    id = 6LwvafOJLSQsbhJwu8MJjYI3;
    name = person3;
    profileImageUrl = "<null>";
}]
```

And this is my whole code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        let friendUser: NSDictionary?
        friendUser = friendsDic[indexPath.row]
        if cell!.isSelected {
            cell!.isSelected = false
            if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
            }
            else {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            }
        }

        if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark {
            let named = friendUser?["name"] as! String
            let urlImg = friendUser?["profileImageUrl"] as? String
            let id = friendUser?["id"] as! String
            let email = friendUser?["email"] as! String
            let dicc: [String: String?] = ["name": named, "email": email, "id": id, "profileImageUrl": urlImg]

            databaseRef.child("selectedfriends").child(id).child(CurrentUserID!).setValue(true)

            selectedUser.append(dicc as NSDictionary) 
            MapPage.selectedUsersInfo = selectedUser as! [NSDictionary]
        }

        if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none {
            let id = friendUser?["id"] as! String
            databaseRef.child("selectedfriends").child(id).child(CurrentUserID!).setValue(false)

            var i = indexPath.row
            selectedUser.remove(at: i)

            MapPage.selectedUsersInfo = selectedUser as! [NSDictionary] 
     }
}
```

Comment: Your question is garbled. You say you have a dictionary, and you define your variable as a dictionary, but the data you show is an array of dictionaries. You can't use the method `remove(at:)` on a dictionary. That's an array method.

Comment: But there is no any relevant remove method except `remove(at: )`

Comment: I agree with @DuncanC, you have other various confusing things in your code. But if you wish to remove a Dictionary key, the correct way is to use **remove(forKey:)**.

Comment: You have an **ARRAY** of NSDictionary objects, not a dictionary. What do you mean about "I’m adding these members to dictionary when i checked one of them on tableview...". Post an entire method that is supposed to remove an item from your table view, and explain how that method gets called. Are you trying to let the user delete a cell when the system `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)`?

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift – always use a native Swift dictionary instead. Although that being said, your data looks like an array of static fields – therefore you want an array of structs.

Comment: @DuncanC I added whole method. @Hamish i can't use the without NS prefix because complier wants `<Key: Hashable>, Any>?` but i dont know how i handle with these parameters.

Comment: You could make your dictionary type `[String:Any]` or `[String:String]`. (`String` keys and values of type `Any`, or `String` keys and `String` values.)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not make sense. It looks like you have a data structure `friendsDic` that is an array of dictionaries containing an entry for every cell in your table view.

When the user selects a cell you extract the fields from that cell's `friendsDic` entry and use those fields to build a NEW dictionary that you append to the end of an array `selectedUser`.

When the user deselects  a cell you try to use the row of the cell in the table view to remove that entry from `selectedUser`, but the `selectedUser` array's elements will not be in any particular order (They'll be in the order in which the user checked them.) Even if they do happen to be in the same order as the entries in the `friendsDic` array, the array indexes won't match up because the non-selected items from `friendsDic` won't be in the `selectedUser` array. That's why you are getting index out of range errors.

It looks to me like your design is flawed and needs to be reworked.

You need to step back and explain what you're trying to do (app function) at a higher level, and then logically how you have attempted to implement that functionality.

### EDIT:

Please stop describing your data model as a dictionary. It's not. You have an array. The elements of the array are dictionaries. As Hamish said in his comment, an array of structs would be a better choice, but you could make an array of dictionaries work.

I suggest not trying to maintain a second array of selected items. You can set up the table view to support multiple selection, and then use the method `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get an array of index paths of the selected rows.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add friendsDic dictionary. The function of tableview as you explained, i want to add the user to the dictionary when i select the cell, because i'm gonna use later to reach more informations(key and values) about users. However, when i deselect the user, the user information must be deleted from dictionary.  But problem is indexes not same, If I add latest the person who is first(person1) on the tableview, it will be lasest person in dictionary.

Comment: And when i deselect the first person(person1) to delete from dictionary, it will delete first person of dictionary, not tableview's first person or the person who i select. cause there is a mismatch at indexPath.row.

Comment: "But problem is indexes not same, If I add latest the person who is first(person1) on the tableview, it will be lasest person in dictionary." Put another way, your design is fundamentally flawed and needs to be reworked.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thank you.